# What is the meaning of ATS_PACKNAME?

Tags: ats

For instance, I saw the following line in ATSLIB:

```
#define ATS_PACKNAME "ATSLIB.libats.deqarray"
```

What is the meaning of this line? What purpose does it serve?

Answer (score 2):

> Say you declare a function in a file XYZ.dats:
>
> extern fun foo (...): ...
>
> The ATS compiler generates a global name for foo using the full path
>   of XYZ.dats, which is often hard to read.
>
> If the flag ATS_PACKNAME is set, then the global name for foo is
>   ${ATS_PACKNAME}foo, where ${ATS_PACKNAME} is the string value of
>   ATS_PACKNAME.

http://discourse.ats-lang.org/t/ats-packname/645/2